# Teradata BTEQ - Can't find, access or install it

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, bteq

Does Teradata Vantage and Teradata SQL Assistant come with BTEQ?  If yes, how do I access it?  If no, how do I install it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's part of Teradata Tools and Utilities download.

Comment: You'll find the TTU at https://downloads.teradata.com/search/node/ttu%20install

Comment: Thanks guys!!! Can BTEQ be used for some automation in Teradata? If yes, what are some use cases?